# EPPlus AddPicture causes Excel 2007 file corruption

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I'm trying to add some pictures in a Excel 2007 Workbook via EPPlus but when i use 
From.Column and From.Row I get this error when opening the generated xlsx file:

[image]

Thanks in advance for your help.
Here's my code:

```
    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < row.ItemArray.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!row.ItemArray[i].ToString().Contains(';'))
            {
                wrksht.Cells[_rows, i + 1].Value = row.ItemArray[i];
            }
            else
            {
                if (row.ItemArray[i].ToString().Split(';')[0] == "img")
                {
                    if (File.Exists(row.ItemArray[i].ToString().Split(';')[1]))
                    {
                        System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(row.ItemArray[i].ToString().Split(';')[1]);
                        OfficeOpenXml.Drawing.ExcelPicture pic = wrksht.Drawings.AddPicture(
                                (_rows + i * new Random(_rows + i).Next()).ToString(), img
                                );
                        pic.SetSize(img.Width + 5, img.Height + 5);
                        pic.From.Column = i + 1;
                        pic.From.Row = _rows;
                        pic.From.RowOff = ExcelHelper.Pixel2MTU(1);
                        pic.From.ColumnOff = ExcelHelper.Pixel2MTU(1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        _rows++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var img = Image.FromFile(row.ItemArray[i].ToString().Split(';')[1]);
var pic = wrksht.Drawings.AddPicture((_rows + i * new Random(_rows + i).Next()).ToString(), img);
//pic.SetSize(img.Width + 5, img.Height + 5);
//pic.From.Column = i + 1;
//pic.From.Row = _rows;
//pic.From.RowOff = ExcelHelper.Pixel2MTU(1);
//pic.From.ColumnOff = ExcelHelper.Pixel2MTU(1);
pic.SetPosition(_rows-1, 0, i, 0); // always one less than actual value
```

Answer (score 0):

The line you used:

```
System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(row.ItemArray[i].ToString().Split(';')[1]);
```

If you convert Image to Bitmap then problem will solve. You can try following code:

```
Bitmap newImage= new Bitmap(System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(row.ItemArray[i].ToString().Split(';')[1]));
```

This may solve your problem.